# разные размеры контролов при создании вручную и в конструкторе, С#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]помогите разобраться в чем проблема - есть необходимость создания контролов вручную в классе, но размер не совпадает с тем же контролом созданным в конструкторе форм из панели элементов, см картинки - dataGridView (на карнинке номер:

1. создан вручную (с размером: 775, 300), следующим кодом:

   c#

   ```
   DataGridView dataGridView;
   GroupBox group;

   dataGridView = new DataGridView();
   group = new GroupBox();

   dataGridView.Size = new Size(775, 300);
   dataGridView.Location = new Point(12, 74);
   dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
   dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
   dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
   dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
   dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
   dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
   dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 143);
   dataGridView.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
   dataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
   dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 40;
   dataGridView.TabIndex = 1;
   dataGridView.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(DataGridView_SelectionChanged);

   group.Size = new Size(1038, 485);
   group.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
   ```
2. создан в конструкторе - но в программе размер окна 2 оказывается меньшим несмотря на то, что в конструкторе указан **больший** размер (1384; 775).
   как это побороть, думал нарисую подходящие размеры в конструкторе и скопирую их в код - но по факту размеры не соответствуют вообще...

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас случаем масштабирование в Windows не включено?

Comment: экран 4к, поэтому масштабирование 225%, но при изменении масштаба (при перезагрузке) - размеры все равно не соответствуют...